# How can I update mare rows at the same time from the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have this table:

[image: How the table looks]

And I want to update the column `Distance` to determinate with a subquery the distance for all records `where name='drive_through'`

This is the expected result:

[image: This should be the expected result]

So far I've done this but I don't understand how I can make the update for each row in a single query

```
UPDATE Action
SET [distance] = (SELECT [distance]
                  FROM Action
                  WHERE [name] = 'travel')
WHERE [name] = 'drive_through'
```

PROBLEM: if I want the second record where the ownerid is the same like in the screenshot above where the owner id is 9690, distance to pe 0.000 instead of 72.841, how should I modify the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you want a correlated subquery.  I would guess:

```
UPDATE Action
    SET [distance] = (SELECT SUM([distance])
                      FROM Action a2
                      WHERE [name] = 'travel' AND a2.ownerID = Action.ownerId
                    )
   WHERE [name] = 'drive_through';
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff And if i want that the second record where the ownerid its the same like in the picture above where de owner id it 9690, distance to pe 0.000 instead of 72.841, how should I modify the query?

Comment: @johnnyReed . . . You should ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**A. Correlate your subquery.**  This means add a line that connects the row you're updating to a row from the subquery (since currently the subquery will return many rows, hence the error):

```
UPDATE A
SET [distance] = (SELECT DISTINCT [distince]
                  FROM Action A2
                  WHERE [name] = 'Travel'
                  AND A.ownerID = A2.ownerID) --Here
FROM Action A
WHERE [name] = 'drive_through'
```

**B. Use a join**

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[distince] = A2.[distance]
FROM Action A
JOIN Action A2 ON A.ownerID = A2.ownerID
WHERE A.name = 'drive_through'
AND A2.name = 'Travel'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would involve using a JOIN with another instance of the same table.

```
UPDATE a1 
SET a1.distance = a2.distance 
FROM Action a1 
JOIN Action a2 ON a1.OwnerID = a2.OwnerID 
WHERE a1.name = 'drive_through'
```